# Return value between Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-dsl

I have two pipelines, that works isolated between each other. And a third that invoked both of them, and it require information returned by one of them.

From the Pipeline `C` invoke `service-docker-build` and I want to obtain the Docker image tag created in that pipeline.

```
                    def dockerBuildResponse = build job: "service-docker-build", propagate: false
                    IMAGE_TAG = dockerBuildResponse.getBuildVariables()["IMAGE_TAG"]
```

In the `service-docker-build` pipeline I define this variable

```
IMAGE_TAG = Globals.nexus3PrdUrl.replaceAll("^https?://", "") + "/" + Globals.image.imageName()
```

But I still have in pipeline `C` the `IMAGE_TAG` a null

Any idea how can I pass this value to the invoker pipeline?

Regards

Comment: You can try defining the IMAGE_TAG as an environment variable in Jenkins. That will be stored along with  other environment variables. So when you run the `service-docker-build` pipeline the value to the environment variable will be updated and then in the pipeline `C` it will be fetched from the  environment variable IMAGE_TAG.